# Why dual __init__ in python?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, super

I am  investigating python oop style. I have seemed `__init__` construction method as below. I did't see this style before. Why use dual `__init__` methods as in this stuff?

**ex-**

```
class MinimumBalanceAccount(BankAccount):
    def __init__(self, minimum_balance):
        BankAccount.__init__(self)
        self.minimum_balance = minimum_balance

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if self.balance - amount < self.minimum_balance:
            print 'Sorry, minimum balance must be maintained.'
        else:
            BankAccount.withdraw(self, amount)
```

Comment: This is just [Understanding Python super() with __init__() methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods) in disguise. But not exactly a duplicate, since it's not obvious what's going on if the code doesn't say `super(...).__init__()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an example of Class inheritance in Python. You have inherited the `BankAccount` Class to the `MinimumBalanceAccount` Class. However, by introducing an `__init__` function in the `MinimumBalanceAccount` Class, you have overridden `__init__` function of `BankAccount` Class. The base class might initialize some variables that are required for you. And hence it is called in the Child class' `__init__` constructor to ensure that.

You can use `super` class to implement the same behavior. 
In Python 2.x, the equivalent will be

```
class MinimumBalanceAccount(BankAccount):
    def __init__(self, minimum_balance):
        self.minimum_balance = minimum_balance
        super(MinimumBalanceAccount, self).__init__()
```

Or in Python 3.x,

```
class MinimumBalanceAccount(BankAccount):
    def __init__(self, minimum_balance):
        super().__init__()
```

However, you must understand that this will just run whatever `__init__` method it finds first from the base methods. So in terms of multiple inheritance, it would be difficult to call `__init__` methods of various other classes, if `super` is not implemented in the base classes. So please avoid using multiple inheritance at all costs or implement `super` in all classes.

```
(eg)

class BankAccount(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # Some action here
        # But no super method called here

class MinimumBalanceAccount(BankAccount, LoanAccount):
    def __init__(self, minimum_value):
        super(MinimumBalanceAccount, self).__init__() # Calls BankAccount.__init__()
        super(MinimumBalanceAccount, self).__init__() # Still calls the same
```

If you still wish to go for Multiple Inheritance, best go with the `ParentClass.__init__` approach or add the `super` method call to `__init__` in all the base classes.

Comment: "However, you must understand that this will just run whatever init method it finds first from the base methods." => sorry but that's at least partly wrong. - as long as the parent classes `__init__` methods do a `super().__init__()` call themselves then all parent's initializers will be called in the right order (ie the `__mro__` order).

Comment: Yes. If there is a super call in the parent class. Then with a single super statement, we will follow the entire resolution. However, if there is no super method in the base class, we could not get to the second `__init__` method other than calling by the class' name. I will update the post with more detail.

Answer (score 1):

The class `MinimumBalanceAccount` derives from the class `BankAccount`. Therefore, in the class' init function, it needs to call the init of the base class, which is done by `BankAccount.__init__(self)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing more than calling `ParentClass.__init__()` in disguise, i.e.

```
super(ChildClass, self).__init__()
```

The preferred Python style is to explicitly use super, rather than hardcode in the name of the parent class.

(In Python 3.x: you can just say `super().__init__()` )

So this is really just [Understanding Python super() with **init**() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods) in disguise; here, *ChildClass* is *MinimumBalanceAccount*